# Android: How to get information about caught exceptions in Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When an app which is deployed in Google Play Store crashes, you see these crash reports. Let's say I have exceptions which are caught and logged with `Log.e`, is there a way to see these exceptions as well in any way? In other words: When I want to see errors that really matters for my workflow, is the only way to see these exceptions in Google Play Developer Console to throw a `RuntimeException` inside the app to crash the app by intention? (That would be really stupid).

Background: I currently implement in-app billing. There are really a lot of phases where possible exceptions can occur while the purchase process. If a customer will contact me and asks why the purchase process didn't work, how should I know if I don't see any information in Google Play Developer Console?

Comment: Check this out: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Firebase Crashlytics**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/)

> Firebase Crashlytics is a lightweight, realtime crash reporter that helps you track, prioritize, and fix stability issues that erode your app quality. Crashlytics saves you troubleshooting time by intelligently grouping crashes and highlighting the circumstances that lead up to them.

**Key capabilities**

- Curated crash reports

  > Crashlytics synthesizes an avalanche of crashes into a manageable list of issues, provides contextual information, and highlights the severity and prevalence of crashes so you can pinpoint the root cause faster.
- Enhanced environment info

  > Crashlytics allows you to filter reports by operating system, version, hardware configuration, and more. Find out if your app is crashing more frequently on a particular manufacturer's devices, with certain API versions, or even in a specific screen orientation.
- Realtime alerts

  > Get realtime alerts for new issues, regressed issues, and growing issues that might require immediate attention.

> **[Get started with Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)**

Comment: As in Spirit's answer mentioned, Firebase only preprocesses crashes that already happend, is that right? Moreover, it does not show the crash report in Google Play Developer console, but in Firebase Console. 
And I don't want more Google dependencies in my app than needed. The more Google services the more problems.

Comment: Nevertheless, it basically answers the question, so I upvote it for now.
(but maybe there are also other solutions)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Fire base crash report service.i have attached the codelabs sample code(Official docs).
[sample code](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#14)

Comment: That basically answers my question, but I'm not 100% confident with it, since I'd rather not use more Google services than needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can technically use Crashlytics or HockeyApp but it probably won't help you because it will only trigger when app crash. I mean that's great but problem is if user have an issue and app didn't crashed like (purchase process didn't completed). You can handle this on following way(I implemented this approach in my apps):

- Create a log file on user device (notice it will require Permission for writing to Storage)
- Send that log to your email address and it will contain every log.e, log.d, log.it etc and it will help you to reproduce a bug

Code:

```
  public static void sendLog(Context context) {
    //set a file
    Date datum = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String fullName = df.format(datum) + "appLog.txt";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fullName);

    //clears a previous log
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    //write log to file
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    try {
        String command = String.format("logcat -d -v threadtime *:*");
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String currentLine = null;
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLine != null && currentLine.contains(String.valueOf(pid))) {
                result.append(currentLine);
                result.append("\n");
            }
        }
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
        out.write(result.toString());
        out.close();
        sendEmail(context, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //clear the log

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Send file to email:

```
private static void sendEmail(Context context, File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"XXXXXXXXXX ENTER EMAIL"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Log Report");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Add description:");
    if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Attachment Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
}
```

Comment: That's a possible solution. I will think about it (or similar solutions)